# How to configure TypeORM in NestJS for using postgres replication?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, replication, nestjs, typeorm

I have setup replication for postgres database in AWS.
How to configure TypeORM to use read/write replicas in NestJs.

My current code looks like this. How to convert this multiple connection to use replications.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'user1',
      password: 'pass1',
      database: 'user1',
      synchronize: true,
      entities: ['src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      migrations: ['./src/migrations/*.ts'],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      name: 'read',
      host: '127.0.0.2',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'user2',
      password: 'pass2',
      database: 'user2',
      entities: ['src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
     migrations: ['./src/migrations/*.ts'],
   })
  ],
  controllers: [HealthCheckController],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

user.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]),
  ],
  exports: [],
  controllers: [UserController],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

user.service.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class OnboardingService {
  private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(UserService.name);

  public constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
    private readonly userEntityRepository: Repository<UserEntity>,
    @InjectConnection()
    private readonly connection: Connection,
  ) {}
```

How to use slave/master connection in user.service.ts file?

Answer (score 4):

To configure replication connection settings you can do:

```
 @Module({
 imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: 'postgres',
    replication: {
      master: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'user1',
      password: 'pass1',
      database: 'user1',
      },
      slaves: [{
        host: '127.0.0.2',
        port: 5432,
        username: 'user2',
        password: 'pass2',
        database: 'user2',
      }]
    },
    entities: ['src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    migrations: ['./src/migrations/*.ts'],
    synchronize: true,
})],
  controllers: [HealthCheckController],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

For more information, you can check : [typeorm Replication](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/multiple-data-sources.md#replication)

Comment: I am not able to use this connection in  TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]).